# OpenVPN auth-ldap cannot find user in a group, but ldapsearch can find it

Tags: openvpn, ldap, authentication, openldap

I can search for a user without issue:

```
ldapsearch -h ldap.my.server.name -b "cn=vpnusers,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com" -x "memberUid=myusername"
```

Results:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <cn=vpnusers,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: memberUid=myusername
# requesting: ALL
#

# vpnusers, groups, example.com
dn: cn=vpnusers,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
gidNumber: 10000
description: Group account
cn: vpnusers
objectClass: posixGroup
memberUid: myusername
memberUid: someuser

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

So I know that the entry is there and it's searchable. However now I'm trying to search that group with openvpn using the `auth-ldap` plugin

Here is my auth-ldap.conf that **works perfectly fine** (when `RequireGroup` = `false`:

```
<LDAP>
        URL             ldap://ldap.my.server.name
        Timeout         10
        TLSEnable       yes
        FollowReferrals yes
</LDAP>

<Authorization>
        BaseDN          "ou=users,dc=example,dc=com"
        SearchFilter    "(uid=%u)"
        RequireGroup    false
                <Group>
                        BaseDN  "ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com"
                        SearchFilter "cn=vpnusers"
                        MemberAttribute memberUid
                </Group>
</Authorization>
```

If I update it to require group search, it fails:

```
<LDAP>
        URL             ldap://ldap.my.server.name
        Timeout         10
        TLSEnable       yes
        FollowReferrals yes
</LDAP>

<Authorization>
        BaseDN          "ou=users,dc=example,dc=com"
        SearchFilter    "(uid=%u)"
        RequireGroup    true
                <Group>
                        BaseDN  "ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com"
                        SearchFilter "cn=vpnusers"
                        MemberAttribute memberUid
                </Group>
</Authorization>
```

The error that the openvpn server spits out is:

```
Dec  6 18:54:37 openvpn01 openvpn: Thu Dec  6 18:54:37 2018 47.153.170.228:1194 PLUGIN_CALL: POST /usr/lib64/openvpn/plugin/lib/openvpn-auth-ldap.so/PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY status=1
Dec  6 18:54:37 openvpn01 openvpn: Thu Dec  6 18:54:37 2018 47.153.170.228:1194 PLUGIN_CALL: plugin function PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY failed with status 1: /usr/lib64/openvpn/plugin/lib/openvpn-auth-ldap.so
Dec  6 18:54:37 openvpn01 openvpn: Thu Dec  6 18:54:37 2018 47.153.170.228:1194 TLS Auth Error: Auth Username/Password verification failed for peer
```

Works fine if I'm not using the `RequireGroup` option so I assume my `MemberAttribute` or `SearchFilter` is wrong. Any ideas? Anyone hit this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same problem trying to use JumpCloud's LDAP service. What worked for me was wrapping the search filter in parenthesis:

```
searchFilter "(cn=vpnusers)"
```